# Confusing algebra in infinite series of complex

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

In a proof of the book "Complex Analysis" by Zakeri, on page 12 we have the following equality, which I can't make sense of,

$\sum^\infty_{n=2}a_n(\frac{z^n-z^n_0}{z-z_0}-nz^{n-1}_0)=(\sum^N_{n=2}+\sum_{N+1}^\infty)a_n(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}z_0+\dots+z^{n-1}_0-nz^{n-1}_0)$

I tried so many ways but couldn't figure out how this equality works, can someone help me understand? thanks

Comment: Try just multiplying the $(z^{n-1}+...)$ by $z-z_0$ and see what you get

Comment: @copper.hat ah thanks, it seems I got the original quotient back, but still, I'm puzzled on how did it went from the quotient to the sum on the other side. I'm not sure what method of algebra was used.

Comment: It's a geometric sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks the comment, I think we can manipulate the quotient to $$z^{n-1}\frac{1-(\frac{z_0}{z})^n}{1-\frac{z_0}{z}}$$, then by geometric sum formula we can conclude the RHS of the equality.